# double click function by JQuery doesn't work on radio input in FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I wrote below code to remove checked item from radio group in my form by double click.

```
$("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
            $(this).dblclick(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            });
        });
```

but this code doesn't work in FireFox but work in IE.
anybody know what's the problem?

tanx

Answer (score 2):

Either way, you probably want to wire it up a little differently.

```
$("input[type='radio']").dblclick(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```

One thing that can help when learning jQuery is to think set-based, like SQL. Selectors can select one or a group of elements. Any function or event you call on the group applies to the whole group.

Comment: Wow. Did not notice the date. Oh well, I probably won't help Ata - but maybe I can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I am so sorry, It works. I think cache makes this issue.

Comment: Hi,

Can you please explain "catch" ?